# Editing a Dataframe format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## I have this DataFrame [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi8On.png) that has a year associated with a column for each entry value (each year is a column). However, I need to format it so that it has a single column named "Year" for which each value refers to the year of the observation.[This is how it has to end up looking like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO75H.png)

I am a beginner, so haven't been able to do much on this, since I am not familiar with many pandas commands.